# Hangfire Dashboard authorization ends up in infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I've configured hangfire server on my local machine. I use dashboard and added dashboard authorization as it was described in this documentation https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDB");
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    var options = new DashboardOptions()
    {
        Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[]
        {
            new DashboardAuthorization()
        }
    };

    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);

    InitializeJobs();
}

public class DashboardAuthorization : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        return CommonUtils.IsIpAddressValid(ipAddress.Trim());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Authorize` function is called infinitely. Any solution?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the stacktrace each time. This could you tell more what is calling Authorize each time.

Comment: couldn't really determine anything by looking at Environment.Stacktrace (is that what you meant?) I'm new to that stuff

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This works locally but when it's deployed it redirects infinitely.